# Lifecycle of fragments on a hosting ViewPager activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, lifecycle

I have two fragments on an activity hosting them, by a ViewPager.
When I update Fragment A's data , it doesn't on the display.
So I figured I should play with the lifecycle...I placed locates at all of the lifecycle callbacks and none were invoked when I was sliding through the fragments. 
Don't the fragments change though the lifecycle when you slide between them?
So how do you refresh their content ?

my code as an exmaple:

fragment b :
when a button is clicked it needs to update the list in fragment A and fragment should display it.

```
private RemoveFromHistoryInterface removeFromHistory = new RemoveFromHistoryInterface()
{
    @Override
    public void removeFromHistory( List<Password> passwordsToRemove )
    {
        PagerActivity.removeFromHistory( passwordsToRemove );
    }
};

public interface RemoveFromHistoryInterface
{
    public void removeFromHistory( List<Password> passwordsToRemove  );
}
...
...

removeFromHistory.removeFromHistory( listToRemove );
```

Pager activity (which is hosting both fragments)

```
public static void removeFromHistory( List<Password> passwordsToRemove )
    {
        MainFragment.fromHistoryToMain( passwordsToRemove );
    }
```

Fragment A :

@

```
Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        passwords = PasswordManager.getInstance().getPasswords();
        passwordsList = Password.getPasswordsList();
    }
...
...
    public static void fromHistoryToMain( List<Password> listBackToMain )
        {
            passwordsList.addAll( 0, listBackToMain );
        }
```

viewpager adapter:

```
  public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Main", "History" };

    public ViewPagerAdapter( FragmentManager fragmentManager ) 
    {
        super( fragmentManager );
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem( int position ) 
    {
        switch ( position ) 
        {
            case 0:
                return new MainFragment();

            case 1:
                return new HistoryFragment();   
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle( int position ) 
    {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you're populating your ViewPager fragments - for example by a cursor...

Comment: edited the post with the briefs of my code..
I'm not using a Cursor. What are my options now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to know when your fragment becomes visible/on screen you can add this into your fragment:

```
@Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) 
    { do_your_stuff }
    else {  }
  }
```

Comment: nope.. I just need to refresh my data displayed. A way to call onCreateCiew again... is it possible?
The data in that fragment does get updated, but it's not shown on the textview widget..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recreate your Fragments every time you scroll your ViewPager, you can call [`setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) on the ViewPager instance.

This will make your ViewPager to totally recreate your Fragments on each page changing.

This can cause some performance flaws as the Fragments will be recreated during the swipe.